# function as parameter in kotlin with default argument

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a function who have another function as parameter, and i want to set default function to my function parameter.

here i have a function like this

```
public fun showDialog(context: Context, title: String = "-", mode: String = "info", type: String = "info", onOk : (dialog: Dialog) -> Unit = { onClickOk(dialog)) }) {

val dialog = Dialog(context)
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
dialog.setCancelable(false)
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.modal_dialog)
dialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

dialog.dialogText.text = title

if (mode.equals("dialog")) {
    dialog.dialogYesNo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    dialog.optionOk.visibility = View.GONE
} else {
    dialog.dialogYesNo.visibility = View.GONE
    dialog.optionOk.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

if (type.equals("success")) {
    dialog.optionOk.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_rounded_success)
    dialog.dialogAlert.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_alert_success)
} else if (type.equals("fail")) {
    dialog.optionOk.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_rounded_fail)
    dialog.dialogAlert.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_alert_fail)
} else {
    dialog.optionOk.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_rounded_primary)
    dialog.dialogAlert.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_alert_info)
}

dialog.optionOk.setOnClickListener{
    onOk(dialog)
}

dialog.show()
}
```

and here my onClickOk function

```
public fun onClickOk (dialog: Dialog){
    dialog.hide()
}
```

my function as parameter is in this code :

```
onOk : (dialog: Dialog) -> Unit
```

and i give a default argument to my function parameter in this code

```
onOk : (dialog: Dialog) -> Unit = { onClickOk(dialog)) }
```

but i can't passing the "dialog" parameter on `onOk` function to `onClickOk` function

this is my error code screenshot

[image]

can someone help me please ? Thanks

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/default-argument-parameter-s-in-functions-kotlin-210e2bf036e0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names in the function type notation are only for the documentation purposes and you won't be able to use them in the lambda's body:

> The function type notation can optionally include names for the function parameters: (x: Int, y: Int) -> Point. These names can be used for documenting the meaning of the parameters

If your lambda has only one argument, you can use an implicit `it` parameter to refer to the argument:

```
onOk: (dialog: Dialog) -> Unit = { onClickOk(it) }
```

In case of two or more arguments you have to declare them inside the lambda's body:

```
onOk: (Dialog, String) -> Unit = { dialog, title -> onClickOk(dialog, title) }
```

Comment: it worked.. thanks, so how if they have more than one argument ? example ```onOk: (dialog: Dialog, title: String) -> Unit = { onClickOk(param1,param2) }``` what should i change for ```param1``` and ```param2``` ?

Comment: @RizalSidik I've edited my answer with an example of a two-parameter lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass method reference:

```
onOk : (dialog: Dialog) -> Unit = this::onClickOk
```

Comment: so you've changed your function declaration to this: `fun showDialog(context: Context, title: String = "-", mode: String = "info", type: String = "info", onOk : (dialog: Dialog) -> Unit = this::onClickOk)`  and still got an error? What error you have?